# ActivationException when running a windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, enterprise-library

I have a Windows Form Application when i installed it on my local machine it is giving the following error:-

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation
>   error occured while    trying to get instance of type LogWriter, key
>   "" ---> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException:
>   Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter", name =
>   "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The type LogWriter cannot be constructed.
>   You must configure the container to supply this value.

Comment: You should update your unity config so that it can find the implementation of LogWriter.

Comment: Include any Unity configuration  in the question, either from your app.config file or from code.

Comment: Can u please tell me how can i update it as i had configured my App.config file using Microsoft Enterprise Library V5 Configuration Editor

Comment: @Akshay - I have never used that tool myself so I can't help you with that. I usually just open my config files in the VS editor and hand edit them. There should be a section in your config for `Unity`. It may also point to a separate `Unity.config` file, in which case you need to edit that file.

Comment: @pstrjds-Actually my probelem is that when i am creating setup and installing my windows form it is giving the above mentioned error else when i am opening the .exe file from my debug it is working fine i think the error is in creating setup can u help me out please???

Comment: Are you deploying your "appname.exe.config"?

Comment: @Tuzo yes i deployed my appname.exe.config now and it's working fine thanks to all

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension in your Unity configuration, either via XML or by code? That's the piece that knows how to read the Entlib logging configuration and turn it into container registrations.